# How to call an Oracle procedure from Java callablestatement with typed params?

Tags: java, oracle, object, jdbc, procedure

I've to call from a Java application with JDBC Oracle driver a stored procedure in a Oracle DB in wich some parameters are simple types (VARCHAR2, NUMBER, ...) and others are objects or event table of object.

```
create or replace 
type t_TYPE as object (In_PARAM VARCHAR2(255)   );

create or replace 
type t_TYPE_array is table of t_TYPE ;

PROCEDURE SOME_PROC (in_myParam IN t_TYPE_array, out_retVal OUT NUMBER) AS ...
```

I'm on Java 1.6 and ojdbc6, my way is for java.sql.CallableStatement, but I'm open to other solutions (on top of the JDBC driver).

P.S. It's an Enterprise app running in Jboss 5 (connection from a datasource).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Found myself:

```
StructDescriptor structDesc = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor(TYPE_STRUCT, dbConnection);
ArrayDescriptor arrayDesc = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(TYPE_ARRAY, dbConnection);

Object[] objType = new Object[1];
objType[0] = new String("param data");
oracle.sql.STRUCT struct = new oracle.sql.STRUCT(structDesc, dbConnection, objType);

Object[] arrayObj = new Object[size];
arrayObj[0] = struct;
arrayObj[1] = struct1;
[...]
oracle.sql.ARRAY array = new oracle.sql.ARRAY(arrayDesc, dbConnection, arrayObj);

callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(MY_CALL);
[...]
callableStatement.setArray(4, array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it with something like this for some stored proc that accepts a VARCHAR and a number as inputs with a numeric output.

```
    Connection conn = null;
    CallableStatement cs = null;
    try {
        conn = dataSource.getConnection();
        cs = conn.prepareCall("{ CALL pkg.someproc(?,?,?) }");

        //populate stored proc parameters
        cs.setString(1, param1);
        cs.setInt(2, param2);
        cs.registerOutParameter(3, Types.NUMERIC); 

        //execute stored procedure
        cs.execute();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is a simple call with native type params... My problem is about complex type params :(

Comment: sure, what kind of params are we talking about? :) If you need arrays, you can use oracle.sql.ARRAY, then cs.setArray

Comment: Hum, you can find parameters definition in the body of the question! :)